# Compiling C++ boost dynamic_bitset code in Ubuntu

Tags: c++, boost, compilation

I have used boost's dynamic_bitset in my code. I wanted to know if I should include any boost library for the code. I read that we just have to include the boost path in the include directives and boost should work fine ( [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846566/using-boost-on-ubuntu) ).

But when I try to compile my code, I get the following error.

boost/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.hpp: No such file or directory

Here is a simple boost code that makes use of dynamic_bit.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp>
//  Also tried giving the entire boost path
//  #include "/home/user_name/BOOST_CPP/boost_1_50_0/boost_1_50_0/boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp"
    using namespace std;
    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
        cout<<"Welcome to Boost"<<endl;
        boost::dynamic_bitset<> x(10);
        return 0;
    }
```

[edit]
I compiled using `g++ boost_hello.cpp` Am I missing something?
Where I can I find what libraries I should include for compiling boost code.?

PS: I followed [Jedf's blog](http://blog.jedf.com/2012/06/installing-boost-libraries-150-on.html) for installing boost libraries at it was successful.

Comment: What command do you use to compile your code? And where did you install Boost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your include directive is not correct. Your error seems to indicate that the `#include <boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp>` is working, however, that header does `#include "boost/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.hpp"` and that is the header your error is complaining about.

I'm assuming you're using g++, most likely you need something like `g++ -I /home/user_name/BOOST_CPP/boost_1_50_0/boost_1_50_0/` in your compilation command line.

If you'll show the command you're using to compile we can probably tell for sure.

Comment: I compiled using `g++ boost_hello.cpp` Am I missing something?

Comment: That worked. :) I had to include my boost location while compiling it.